# Prevent a command in a shellscript from being executed inside another shellscript

Tags: shell, unix, command, delete-file

I am invoking a shellscript inside another shellscript, and the invoked one has a command to delete a folder, which I don't want to be executed, like this

```
$ rm ../temp -rf
```

Is there a way to prevent this command from being executed without changing the invoked script contents?

Comment: Maybe using `alias` wasn't such a good idea, it works in interactive shell only, unless you change the default behaviour with `shopt -s expand_aliases` in the script, see also: http://chiefsandendians.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/linux-scripts-and-alias.html

Comment: If you cannot change that script then you should still be able to make a copy of it and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an alias like this in your script:

```
alias rm='echo SAFE'
```

By default aliases work only in interactive shells, so you must change this behaviour with:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

in your script and source the other script (the one you cannot change):

```
source the_other_script.sh
```

or

```
. the_other_script.sh
```

This will work unless the other script runs `rm` in a sub-shell.

Another, safer method is to create your own `rm` command which does nothing (or just prints out its argument so you know what's going on), put it into a directory and put this directory as the first one in the `PATH` environment variable like this (Korn shell syntax):

```
$ export PATH=/path/to/your/dummy/rm/replacement:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, it was that simple!

Comment: Aliases are not expanded by non-interactive shells by default. It is unlikely the script you are calling has activated alias expansion.

Comment: @chepner OK, but it should work when you `source` the other script, shouldn't it?

Comment: That depends on whether you source it from an interactive or non-interactive shell.

Comment: @chepner When you source from a script which modifies the default behaviour with `shopt -s expand_aliases` it should work as well. I modified my answer and added another method.